# stop previous Handler postdelayed and start new

Tags: java, android, handler

I am using Handler `postDelayed()` to start a timer for 7 secs. if during this interval I receive a reply from server I will stop the timer. but if the reply isnt recieved within 7 sec it will show error.

I am using this code for the purpose

```
handler = new Handler();

Runnable wait4TO = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(pressedButton==INACTVE) ;
        // if reply is recieved pressedbutton will be INACTIVE

        else
        {
            sentFailed();
        }

    }
};

handler.postDelayed(wait4TO, 7000 );
```

It works correctly, but if another message is sent I want to cancel this timeout and start a new one or extend the existing timeout for another 7 secs. How can I acheive this?

I tried cancelling the handler by using `handler.removeCallbacks(wait4TO)` and `handler.removeCallbacks(null)` but no success. the previous handler will still run

Comment: that's strange. Are you sure you have only ONE instance of the handler object?

Comment: @blackbelt well the code above is called whenever i send a message

Comment: so do you create a new handler for every message you send? It would be better you could post a bit more of code/context

Comment: @blackbelt `handler = new Handler();` is called every time... I will try to remove it from the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`removeCallbacks` works. Just be aware of the fact that every handler as its own queue, and in your case, to achieve what you want, you need only one instance of Handler.

Answer (score 2):

So maybe try add flag that you check in runnable

```
boolean flag=true;

Runnable wait4TO = new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
 if(!flag)
 return;
        if(pressedButton==INACTVE) ;
        // if reply is recieved pressedbutton will be INACTIVE

        else
        {
            sentFailed();
        }

    }
};

handler.postDelayed(wait4TO, 7000 );
```

And when You want to deactivate it You just set flag to false;

Eventually try

> handler.removeCallbacs(wait4TO);